# Why is php base64_decode is returning null?

Tags: php, android, base64

I have encoded a bitmap into a Base64 string from a java method. I then sent this string as JSON to a php webservice which will insert this into a longBlob.

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAtAAAAQOCAYAAADysw/5AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU\neJzs3c1WG1maLuBwr76A8A004szPkuxxrxJ4Xghzxg6cfcbgco0L48weW.....

But for some reason, when I do

```
$cust_sign = base64_decode($encodedString);

`$cust_sign` is `null`.
```

This is what I use to encode:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,50,baos);
        byte[] bytes=baos.toByteArray();
        String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I also have this in the php script:

```
if (base64_decode($cust_sign, true)) 
   { 
       echo "valid"; 
   }
```

Which it did echo valid

Do you any idea why?

Thank you

Comment: Did you wrap it in single quotes or double ones?

Comment: It appears that you have some problems with your base64 encoded string, I see linebreaks in it.

Comment: Posting a chunk of the encoded string isn't much help!

Comment: What does `\n` stand for here: a line break or `\ ` followed by `n`?

Comment: Seems to work okay [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/giCK0K)

Comment: Please provide the encoding logic so we can take a look at how the string is being encoded.

Comment: Congratulations, you have a base64 encoded png.

Comment: Textbook too localized

Comment: When I said "Posting a chunk of the string doesn't help" I didn't mean "post the entire string"!  Try and construct a test case with a small string that highlights the issue

Comment: My bad, I did not understand what you meant. I edited the question with the encoding code

Comment: You need to install Gd library in order to use base64. Using terminal, type this: sudo yum install php5-gd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason your string contains line breaks ( \n ). Remove them and it should work.

*Edit:* Try changing the second parameter in Base64.encodeToString() from Base64.DEFAULT to Base64.NO_WRAP.

Comment: I will try it removing the \n

Comment: What happens when you use NO_WRAP?

Comment: I managed to make it work. I removed the \n before sending it to the web-service and managed to decode it on the server-side. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the strict parameter to check if the string contains character from outside the base64 alphabet. If the function returns FALSE, it might by a sign that you have a malformed base64 string

Comment: I added the strict parameter as you said and it is valid. I used this:
if (base64_decode($cust_sign, true)) {
    echo "valid";
}
Which it did echo valid

Answer (score 0):

"\" is not included in Base64.  It seems you have line breaks in your code "\n".  It is not your decoding that is failing, it is how you are encoding your content.  Update your question with the process you are using, and I will be more edit my answer to be more specific.